# express not responding to route

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs and express for api end points, I am using `app.use` to handle a route, but it is not responding no matter what I do.

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var config = require('./conf/config');

var PORT = config.PORT;

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB);

//route handlers

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Hello");
});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log("Request received", req.url);
});

server.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server running on port", PORT);
```

It should print hello on console whenever I request on root route i.e. `/` but it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Express code is not correct.  You are creating a plain web server, but that web server is not hooked up to Express in any way.  If you aren't trying to create any special kind of server (like an https server), then you can just let Express create the server for you with `app.listen(PORT)` and then it will create a server and hook itself up to that server.

I would suggest this:

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");

var app = express();

var config = require('./conf/config');
var PORT = config.PORT;

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB);

//route handlers

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Hello");
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log("Server running on port", PORT);
```

Note: I changed a couple other things too.  I switched to `app.get()` and I inserted a `res.send()` since you need to always send some kind of response of the browser will just wait and wait for something to come back.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `app.get` instead of `app.use`, as well. The latter is used for mounting sub-routes, using middleware etc. but not for actually configuring request handlers.

Comment: Yes I am using this in sub-routes manner, just edited to paste here.