# My nodejs server can't see my requests that I send in reactjs with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building an application that includes react and nodejs in it..
It started yesterday, I saw that suddenly the server does not respond to the requests I sent through the axios package in reactjs..
The server just ignores.
I see that in the network window in dev tools a request to the server is sent but there is no response from the server..
I tried to put middleware in the application that will check if the server accepts sent requests:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
     console.log(req.path);
     next()
})
```

And I didn't see an answer.. it's so frustrating (I've been on this problem for two days now)
What am I doing wrong? The request is sent from an application because I see it through the network..
An important thing: I saw once that after a very long time the server received the request I sent to it.. I send a lot of requests to the server through the application, could there be an overload on the server? I don't know what to think anymore..

Also important: Sometimes the server answers my requests.. 50% of the time it returns an answer and 50% of the time it doesn't..

Server's code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path")
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("./model/userModel")
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
});
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    next()
})

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL).then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connection Successfuly.")
}).catch(err => console.log(err.message));

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Started on Port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: Can you include the frontend (React) code that makes the request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [express not responding to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165709/express-not-responding-to-route)

Comment: Sorry guys for the delay, it worked an hour later, probably bug in my computer